# Lines between single items of a Radiobuttonlist

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

my problem is that I want to use an asp Radiobuttonlist.

And i want to have a line between every single of these dynamically added items.

I already tried everything with borders.

And I tried to put every single item in one cell of a table but i failed.

Please help me out.

EDIT:

Hey thank you very much but one Problem left, i add Items to the radiobuttonlist:

`<asp:RadioButtonList CssClass="mylist" RepeatLayout="Table" RepeatDirection="Vertical" RepeatColumns="1" Font-Size="100%" ID="rb_Varianten" OnSelectedIndexChanged="rb_Varianten_changed" AutoPostBack="true" runat="server"></asp:RadioButtonList>`

and I add items in my VB Code like that:
`rb_Varianten.Items.Add(dv.Table.Rows(i - 1)(int_Name).ToString)`

so it is not possible for me like your suggestion.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT:

The ASP.NET radio button list gets rendered as a table and each radio button gets its own row.  If you want to add a solid or dotted line to the bottom of the table you would do so like this:

(Change `dotted` to `solid` if you do not want a dotted line)

```
    tr td
    {
        border-bottom: 1pt dotted black;
    }
```

Here is a [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nz237/4/).(Updated)

If you want the dotted/solid line to span across the table add

`width: 100%`

Comment: Hey, thanks. But i don't want to add space between them. What i want is a dashed or solid line between every single of these 4 items you created

Comment: Okay, I understand now.  Thought you wanted an extra line between them.  I added CSS to give you a dotted line between each radio button.